# Can I prolongue an expiring date of a provisioning profile? - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a question about provisioning profile, one I generate a provision profile on iOS Provisioning Portal, it always come with expiration date for only a year, does anyone know how to prolongue this date for 2100+, for example?

Is there any way to do that? Or is it impossible to do?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make any change to a certificate which is basically what a provisioning profile is. It has a signed hash.